# Rails, Capybara - capybara cannot find added html elements sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a function below

```
  def fill_in_sources_details
    click_button 'New Source'
    assert_text 'Sources'
    fill_in 'text', :with => @source.text
    fill_in 'url', :with => @source.url
  end
```

After `New Source` clicked, new fields added to the page. Sometimes the test fails because the test doesn't wait for new elements to be added so new fields cannot be found be Capybara. I tried to add `assert_text 'Sources'` which is obvious but it still fails sometimes. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: try to put sleep(5) after button click

Comment: it does increases performance but still fails sometimes though

Comment: Show the error you get

Comment: `Failure/Error: fill_in 'text', :with => @source.text
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "text"
` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things could be going on here, some of which depend on which driver and driver version you're using.

1. You don't actually have a field that matches 'text' - That's not likely here since it works sometimes.
2. The initial `click_button 'New Source'` is missing the actual button.  This could happen depending on which driver you're using if the button animates on to the page (slide in, zoom in, etc).  You can tell if that's what's happening by putting a `sleep 5` before the click_button.   If that fixes the issue then you should look into disabling animation in test mode.  It will speed up your tests and make them more reliable.
3. The `click_button` is happening but it takes too long for the fields to show on the page (slow ajax request, etc).  Putting the `sleep 5` after the click_button should have diagnosed that, however maybe it's taking longer than 5 seconds. The `assert_text 'Sources'` is a good attempt to diagnose that, as long as the text 'Sources' would only be on the page when the input is visible but that text seems too generic for that (it's probably on the current page already). You can always pass a `wait` option to fill_in, which will make it wait longer for the element to appear

   fill_in 'text', :with => @source.text, wait: 20
4. You have an intermittent error in your app that's preventing the fields from showing.  Diagnose that by catching the `ElementNotFound`, pausing the app and looking at the errors in your browser

   begin
     fill_in 'text', :with => @source.text, wait: 20
   rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
     binding.pry # byebug, etc - whatever debugging you use
   end

Comment: Thank you, I tried to increase the sleep time after clicking the button to 60 seconds and the tests still fail. I'm thinking of whether the button is clicked sometimes.

Comment: @TriNguyen did you try a sleep before the click as I suggested in #2